# Emulator Windows 10 Mobile: No Internet connection

Tags: visual-studio, emulation, windows-10-mobile

Since installing the Windows 10 Mobile emulator 10.0.15063 under VS 2017, I can no longer connect to the Internet from the emulator. I didn't have this problem with the Windows 10 Mobile emulator provided with VS 2015.
It seems that the problem comes from setting up the virtual network adapters created during the installation, and the Internet connection mode of the PC hosting the Hyper-V machines (I am connected in WiFi). I can't change the settings correctly (and on the other hand, is it normal to have to edit them?). Thank you to the one who can help me.

Comment: Could you have a try with other versioin emulator? Can other version emulators work well in your device?

Comment: Hello and thank you for your reply.
At first I was working with VS 2015 and the W10 Mobile emulator provides with this version (this emulator was not a Hyper-V virtual machine). And it worked perfectly. Now I'm working with VS 2017 and Hyper-V emulators. It is since this installation that the emulators no longer have access to the Internet.

Comment: Without the specific same environment as your device, I can not see why it happens. You can look into this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2013/10/01/why-cant-the-windows-phone-emulator-go-online/) and check it yourself. On other hand, you can also try to reinstall the Emulater again.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have already reinstalled the emulator several times from 2017 VS, but nothing changes. And I had already seen the blog and followed the instructions to reconfigure the Hyper-V network adapters. Unfortunately, the proposed change does not work: The emulator always starts with its predefined settings, and the connection fails.

Comment: If you deploy the app in your windows phone device, does your app work well? Do you get some error info?

Comment: On my windows phone, everything works correctly: The app can connect to OneDrive and I can do backup. The connection problem on the emulator is independent of my app: when I try to see my account information, the emulator tries to connect, but the connection fails. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I only could provide you this [post](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/738846/How-to-Solve-issues-of-Internet-not-working-with-w) for you to have a try.